# PIC in C - creating own keypad scan routine using RC0-3

Tags: c, pic, mikroc

I have been asked to create my own routine which will scan the keypad, but only using PORTC and using RC0-3, I only need to return 4 values, which are 1,2,4,5 which, if im correct, are in a 2x2 arrangement on a 4x4 keypad. The keypad I am using is a 4x4 keypad connected to PORTC, I am just wondering how you would go about doing this? As I have not been taught this, yet it is a big part of a piece of work, It would be nice if I don't receive a solution, but more an explanation pushing me in the right direction so i can do it myself. 
[PIC Microcontrollers: Scan inputs on a 4x4 Keypad, using only Port C RC0-RC3 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407950/pic-microcontrollers-scan-inputs-on-a-4x4-keypad-using-only-port-c-rc0-rc3-in)
it is basically this question, but the answers on there didnt really help, so I thought I would have a go asking this question myself :)
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous question you linked, the "1,2,4,5" refer to the keypad legends which might be anything and often bear no relation to the bit values you receive back. You write a "1" bit to each output (row) in turn (or a "0" for inverted logic) and look for high (or low if inverted logic) bits on the column inputs. You worry about what is written on the keytops afterwards, by using a lookup table. Whether you have a 2x2 key matrix or a 4x4 is irrelevant, unless you want an in-line solution and not a looped one.

If the keypad really was 2x2 it would not need to be a matrix, the wiring and coding would both be simpler with 4 bits used as inputs instead of 2 out and 2 in to drive and read a matrix.

Unless you rewire the 4x4 keyboard, your 2x2 subset of it will probably be using RC0,1 and RC4,5.

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought, because it is already wired up, but the specification says that we need to use RC0-3, I will be showing the finished product on, and only on Real PIC Simulator, it is a piece of coursework for my final year at university. So if it is on the real pic simulator, could I change the rows and columns to whatever I want?
EDIT: Just had a play on Real PIC simulator, I can wire up the keys however I want, So my next question is, 
How do I setup RC0-1 as outputs, and RC2-3 as inputs? thanks :)

Comment: @user2988392 if the entire device and code are simulated then I would set up the port assignments as the question is asked. RC0,1 as outputs and RC2,3 as inputs. Seems a strange question in an unreal situation. As I remarked above, why use a matrix for 2x2, and on the other hand, surely a 4x4 matrix would not be too taxing for a final year project?

Comment: @user2988392 "**Port C and TRISC Register** Port C is an 8-bit wide, bidirectional port. Bits of the TRISC Register determine the function of its pins. Similar to other ports, a logic one (1) in the TRISC Register configures the appropriate port pin as an input."

Comment: So I set TRISC to 0b00001100 if I want RC0 and RC1 to be outputs? 
Reading:

Set RC0 high, RC1 low
Read RC2. If high, 1 is being pressed
Read RC3. If high, 2 is being pressed
Set RC0 low, RC1 high
Read RC2. If high, 4 is being pressed
Read RC3. If high, 5 is being pressed
Now this part of the answer (obviously it will be different as I have flipped it around), how do I check if they are high? University is quite strange in my opinion, they always ask you to do something that they didnt actually teach us...

Comment: ...not even how to isolate a bit? To read bit 3: `if ((portc & 0x08) != 0) printf ("High");` And that's all the code you'll be getting!

Comment: thank you for your help weather vane :) would you be able to point me to any resources which you would think I would find useful as a beginner when it comes to things like this?

Comment: @user2988392 I googled the PortC data direction using TRISC (I had forgotten) within a few seconds, as I am sure you could have done. I hope you'll give me a vote for the help I have given.